# 404 on starting tomcat server and Tomcat Native Library not found on java library path

Tags: sql-server, apache, tomcat, http-status-code-404

So i started a Tomcat webserver in Eclipse in win 32-bit environment. And i get a `404` webapp not found when pointing to `localhost:8080/HippoWebApp`. The page has some info:

```
The requested resource (/HippoWebApp/) is not available.
```

Eclipse console says:

```
Nov 30, 2012 10:56:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init

INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26-32\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32
```

What am i doing wrong? I read up on APR and it seems like its [harmless warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278047/apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-on-the-java-library-path)

File where context path is set in `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="HippoWebApp">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/target/CalmsWebContent-war"/>
        <dependent-module archiveName="VwCNConfigs-7.3.16.jar" deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/VwCNConfigs/VwCNConfigs">
            <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
        </dependent-module>
        <dependent-module archiveName="VwCNAPI-7.3.16.jar" deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/VwCNAPI/VwCNAPI">
            <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
        </dependent-module>
        <dependent-module archiveName="VwCNAjaxServices-7.3.16.jar" deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/VwCNAjaxServices/VwCNAjaxServices">
            <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
        </dependent-module>
        <dependent-module archiveName="VwCNServices-7.3.16.jar" deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/VwCNServices/VwCNServices">
            <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
        </dependent-module>
        <dependent-module archiveName="VwCNCRAReportService-7.3.16.jar" deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/VwCNCRAReportService/VwCNCRAReportService">
            <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
        </dependent-module>
        <dependent-module archiveName="Web2VwCN-7.3.16.war" deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/Web2VwCN/Web2VwCN">
            <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
        </dependent-module>
        <property name="context-root" value="HippoWebApp"/>
        <property name="java-output-path" value="/HippoWebApp/target/classes"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

Log when starting server:

```
Nov 30, 2012 10:56:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26-32\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\jrockit_150_12\bin;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26-32\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\CA\SharedComponents\ScanEngine;C:\Program Files\CA\SharedComponents\CAUpdate\;C:\Program Files\CA\SharedComponents\ThirdParty\;C:\Program Files\CA\SharedComponents\SubscriptionLicense\;C:\Program Files\CA\eTrustITM;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Program Files\Belgium Identity Card;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26-23\bin;C:\maven\bin;C:\maven\bin;.    
    Nov 30, 2012 10:56:50 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init    
    INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080    
    Nov 30, 2012 10:56:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load    
    INFO: Initialization processed in 794 ms    
    Nov 30, 2012 10:56:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start    
    INFO: Starting service Catalina    
    Nov 30, 2012 10:56:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start    
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.33    
    Nov 30, 2012 10:56:50 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start    
    INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080    
    Nov 30, 2012 10:56:50 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init    
    INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009    
    Nov 30, 2012 10:56:50 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start    
    INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/31  config=null    
    Nov 30, 2012 10:56:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start    
    INFO: Server startup in 409 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The APR warning is not the cause of the HTTP 404.
Could you post the entire Tomcat startup log? Is the application started correctly? Have you set the context path?

If I'm not mistaken the context path is set in the file `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` in the `.settings` folder.